# JQuery Auto Complete substitute for Select Drop Down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using a jQuery Autocomplete widget on a text input to replace a select drop down list. The suggest drop down opens up when a user clicks into the textbox. My solution works great in FireFox but works with a bit of a glitch in Internet Explorer 8. In internet explorer when an item is selected from the suggest drop down the suggest list disappears then re-appears for a brief second. I have no idea how to prevent this.

I am using:
(jquery) jquery-1.6.4.min.js
(jquery UI) jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js

Code Below

```
<input type="text" style="width:200px;" id="txtPosTypeS" value="" />

var RegTempList = [
{ label: "Auxiliary Monthly Trust", value: 1000},
{ label: "Auxiliary Monthly Operating", value: 1001},
{ label: "Auxiliary Hourly Trust", value: 1002},
{ label: "Auxiliary Hourly Operating", value: 1003}]

 $().ready(function() {
    $('#txtPosTypeS').autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: RegTempList,
        delay: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            //if the value of the textbox does not match a suggestion, clear its value
            if ($(".ui-autocomplete li:textEquals('" + $(this).val() + "')").size() == 0) {
                $(this).val('');
                $('#hidPositionType').val('');
            }
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).blur();
            return false;
        }
    })
    .focus(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete('search','');
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    }; });
```

Comment: you are missing:`$.expr[':'].textEquals = function(a, i, m) { return $(a).text().match("^" + m[3] + "$"); }; `

Comment: you are missing semi-colon at end of your array.

Answer (score 2):

Using IE8 and jsfiddle, there is a script error on the textEquals in the change function. Removing the change function, fixes the issue.

Just threw this into jsFiddle, here is the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/BDd9H/

Also, updated the textbox width so the text did not jump.

Comment: Hi I just tried your sample on IE 8 and it still flashed the suggest drop down when you select one of the suggest items. I'm trying to get rid of that annoying re-pop up of the suggest on IE.

Comment: its working but issue is its not setting the value same value as the drop down!