# CSS - Border Radius for the drop down box when using the SELECT tag? Not the SELECT input ittself, the actual drop down box?

Tags: css, select, tags, border

I am trying to style a select drop down box.

So far, I have achieved a styled effect within the drop down box itself (the box that drops down with the options) by applying certain styles to the select tag.

Here is the css I have used so far:

```
input, select {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #6a6f75;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: , 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out 0s;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out 0s;  /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out 0s;  /* IE10? */
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out 0s;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition: all 0.7s ease-out 0s;
}

select {
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

input:focus, select:focus
{
    background: #6699cc;
    color: #e7f3ff;
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #666,
        1px -1px 0 #666,
        -1px 1px 0 #666,
        1px 1px 0 #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
}
```

This css applies to the INPUT and SELECT tags found within a specific page.

Now, this does style the drop down box on the focus event, with the background transforming to blue (works in Firefox) What I want to do though, is add a curved border to the drop down box, so that it blends in more with the select input itself.

This will achieve an effect something like this:

```
( Choose )
( Option )
| Option |
( Option )
```

In comparison to this (please forgive my crude examples):

```
( Choose )
| Option |
| Option |
| Option |
```

I don't know if this is even possible yet, as the background styles I have applied to the select tag are coming into effect, but the border radius styles are only applied to the SELECT input itself and not the drop down box.

Would someone with some more knowledge in this regard, please take a few minutes to enlighten me?

Is it possible to add a curved border to the drop down box, or is it only possible to style the SELECT input with a curved border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve this SELECT DROPDOWN style, with standard HTML form elements, you would have to 'substitute' the dropdown / select with DIV non form elements, then update the selected value to either a hidden form element or a hidden select dropdown.

If you got it somewhat that way you wanted, it would not be cross-browser compatible.

An example of a jQuery substitute is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8450718/158014

Comment: Thank you for your input! As you have provided me with the inspiration behind a good idea :)

Answer (score 4):

As @jakub mentionned, you won't be able to style your select dropdown using `<select>` and `<option>` tags.

That's why I once made this jQuery plugin: [jQuery.simpleselect](http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect/)

It replicates the behavior of a HTML `<select>` using divs so that you can style whatever you want, however you want. And it's really easy to use:

**HTML**

```
<select id="the_select" name="the_select"> 
    <option value="1">One</option> 
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option> 
    <option value="3">Three</option> 
    <option value="4">Four</option> 
</select>​
```

**JS**

```
$("#the_select").simpleselect();
```

**This line of JavaScript will transform your regular `<select>` into the HTML below**

```
<div class="hidden_select_container"> 
  <select id="the_select" name="the_select" class="simpleselected"> 
    <option value="1">One</option> 
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option> 
    <option value="3">Three</option> 
    <option value="4">Four</option> 
  </select> 
</div> 
<div class="simpleselect" id="simpleselect_the_select"> 
  <div class="placeholder">Two</div> 
  <div class="options"> 
    <div class="option">One</div> 
    <div class="option">Two</div> 
    <div class="option">Three</div> 
    <div class="option">Four</div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

This behavior has multiple advantages:

- You keep writing regular `<select>`s, so if one day you want to stop using the plugin, you don't have any HTML to update
- The `<select>` is replaced with `<div>`s, so it's fully styleable
- The `<select>` is hidden, not removed: if the form is submitted, the selected value WILL be submitted like it should be with a regular `<select>`

**Doc and download: [jQuery.simpleselect](http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect/)**