# CSS: How can I round the select box from a drop-down-menu?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to HTML and CSS, but can't find anything or hardly anything on this question. I have a  drop down menu, which already has rounded corners. But how do I get the options to be in a rounded box?

[image]

(This square box should be rounded)

```css
select{
  width: 285px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-color: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="color" class="selectBox" id="color">
    <option value="" disabled hidden selected>select color</option>
    <option value="red"> red </option>
    <option value="blue"> blue </option>
    <option value="green"> green </option>
    <option value="yellow"> yellow </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927974/css-border-radius-for-the-drop-down-box-when-using-the-select-tag-not-the-sel

Comment: do you want to round off the option tags?

Comment: Demo 3 from this [link](https://siteorigin.com/thread/rounded-corners-on-drop-down-sub-menus/) is kind of a rounded menu, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes

Comment: look it, pls - https://select2.org/options

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: You can't do it.

This box is managed by the OS.
If you want to style options, you need to write your own html or use third-party components.

Comment: Okay, that also explains why I couldn't find so much about it

Answer (score 1):

drop-down lists are controlled by the users operating system so full styling of these elements isn't possible.
You can achieve a similar effect by using HTML `<li>` elements and adding JS to it to create the drop-down list, and adding a couple of basic transition effects.